# Android HorizontalScrollView snap

Tags: android, scroll, element, center, horizontalscrollview

So I have a horizontalscrollview and I want to try add a snapping effect, that basically centers an element.
I have done it all in XML basically so far.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
```

And then I have a LinearLayout inside of it.
So how do I go about making the elements inside of the LinearLayout snap? Also, is there a way to make the layout start on the middle element? So when you see the scroller, you can scroll left or right from the start.
Would appreciate any help with this! Thanks guys!

Comment: your question is confusing ,what do u really want.

Comment: please add some more code to understand your problem

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use viewpager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)? 
but if you insist to use horizontal scroll view there are some tutorial out there you can follow like this

> -http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34
>
> -http://blog.velir.com/index.php/2010/11/17/android-snapping-horizontal-scroll/
>
> -http://androidprogrammingmadeeasy.blogspot.com/2011/08/creating-custom-horizontal-scroll-view.html

Comment: I'm not sure how I would use it. Do I make that a class and then add it in using XML or something?